# MYSQL simple DB Design

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

Writing (.net) a simple app that logs whether a user has access to a program or not. Cannot figure out the best way to structure the DB/tables.

Interface will have two listboxes with buttons in between to add/remove items. What is the best way to layout the tables for easy querying?

Thanks (not a DB guy obviously!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading up on basic database design principles if you plan to continue working in this area.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design

http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa200276(v=office.11).aspx

If I understand your question then a table of programs, a table of users, and a "many to many" table where each row contains an id from the user table and an id from the programs table if the user has access should suffice.